# Why doesn't ANSI C directly expose the overflow and carry flags?

Tags: c++, c, integer-overflow, ansi-c

Given

```
int x = a number;
int y = some number;
int z = x + y;  // did overflow occur?
```

At least on Intel chips, overflow detection is possible through the overflow flag.  But there's no direct way to get to it through ANSI C.  Why not?

NOTE: The question is not about how to detect overflow while using ANSI C/C++.  Rather, it's asking why didn't Dennis Ritchie, and later the ANSI C committee, provide this very useful feature.

Comment: i guess there is at least one processor that does not allow overflow detection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect integer overflow in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c)

Comment: @HenriMenke: Nope.  I'm aware of that thread, as well as how to detect overflow within ANSI C/C++.  I'm asking for the reason why Dennis Ritchie, and subsequently the ANSI C standardization committee did not provide for it.

Comment: @tobi303: a) that's what I was guessing, but a friend contradicted me.  So, if that's the answer, then a relevant link is what is required; b) Probably a separate question, but if your guess is correct, why didn't the committee require a simulation of the overflow flag by compiler writers when porting to such processors?  Here, the acceptable answer would have to be more detailed than that it would be expensive.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer in any definitive way - it's like trying to prove a negative.  It's basically going to require someone to stumble upon some official discussion of this, which may well not exist.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth:  a) Hopefully, there are people from the committee lurking around stack overflow; b) I could introduce a series of other questions that try to triangulate an answer to this.  I'll wait a few days till the holiday is over.

Comment: actually it's not available in most programming languages

Comment: @phuclv: No doubt, but C is just one step above assembly, so one would expect more low-level features from it than from most other languages.